# Adding files to a visual studio project with yeoman

Tags: visual-studio-2015, yeoman, yeoman-generator

Is it possible to add files to a visual studio project ( specifically a Blank Azure Node.js Web Application ) during the yeoman generation?

when i run

```
yo foobar
```

It adds the files to the folder system but not to the project itself in visual studio.

Comment: If I remember correctly, there's an option to add every file in the file system in VS.

Comment: Would that be a argument passed into the generation `yo foo --saveToProject` ?

Comment: Yeoman doesn't control your editor. It's up to you to figure out how to add these files to your VS project easily.